# Raster Palet remove categories/colours

Tags: qgis, raster

I'm rather new to QGIS and I have the following issue:

I have a raster image with 255 different categories all having their own colour. However, I want to cut out some of this data as it is not relevant to me. When going to properties > style > paletted, I'm basically searching for a way to delete some of the categories I do not need. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature became available from **QGIS 3.0** onwards where you can edit/remove palettes:

https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog30/index.html#feature-easy-styling-of-discrete-rasters